# AWS t2.medium performance issues after adding 32 gb volume

Tags: amazon-web-services

On AWS EC2 t2.medium instance we run a site http://www.pricesimply.com/

Our database is installed on the same machine.
By default we had 8 gb storage and the site speed was lightning quick.

Then, we added a 32 gb volume Type - general purpose volume.

Only difference between these 2 volumes -

8 gb default volume    - IOPS 24/3000

32 gb new added volume - IOPS 96/3000

Volume type & Availability zones are same.

The site MUCH SLOWER now compared to earlier.

Comment: What is the CPU credit balance? Are you I/o bound?

Comment: CPU credit balance has an average Value : 430 (Count)

Comment: Drupal is deployed on the server. Caching, database logging take place. How can I find out whether we are i/o bound ?

Comment: Look at iostat or the cloud watch stats related to disk.

Comment: There are 16 ebs volume parameters. VolumereadOPs and VolumeWriteOps are between (Count) 15000 to 25000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an additional disk shouldn't slow down your machine, you'll need to investigate things a bit more to identify the bottleneck.

Poor performing infrastructure generally fits into one of three categories:

- **CPU:** Check your CPU utilization to see if the `t2.medium` instance is a suitable size. Amazon CloudWatch can show you CPU history.
- **Memory (RAM):** Your application may be short on memory, causing page swaps to disk. You'll need to monitor memory utilization *from within your instance*. (CloudWatch cannot see memory utilization.)
- **Disk IO:** If you are reading & writing to disk a lot, then this could be your bottleneck. CloudWatch can give you some metrics, especially the **Queue Length**, which indicates that IO was waiting to be processed.

Once you've identified which of these three factors appears to be the bottleneck, try to improve them:

- CPU: **Use a larger instance type**
- Memory: **Use an instance type with more RAM**
- Disk: **Use a faster disk**

You are using **General Purpose (SSD) EBS volumes**. These volumes have an IOPS (Input/Output per second) related to volume size. So, your "96/3000" volume gives a guaranteed 96 IOPS (about the speed of a magnetic hard disk) with the ability to burst up to 3000 IOPS if you have enough IO 'credits'. If you are continually using more than 96 IOPS, you will run out of credits and will be limited to 96 IOPS.

See: [Amazon EBS Volume Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html)

Comment: CloudWatch Queue Length ranges between 6 to 10 throughout  the day. Hence I should use a faster disk. Right ?

Comment: The [EBS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-workload-demand.html) recommends "that you target a queue length of 1 for every 500 IOPS available". Some queuing is good because it means you are getting full value out of the disk (less idle) but too much is bad because it slows things down.

Comment: We moved to Provisioned IOPS (SSD) disk. Now we have 960 IOPS available. For MySQL db AWS recommends Provisioned IOPS (SSD). Our site is working much better after switching the disk.

Answer (score 2):

Some random ideas:

1) Performance does vary between volumes. Do some benchmarks to see if it's really slower. (Unlikely, but possible.)

2) Perhaps the volume is a red herring -- Maybe your entire dataset was small enough to fit into RAM before, and now that you've expanded and grown, your data doesn't fit, creating constant I/O?

3) If the drive was created from a snapshot, it may be [fetching your data from your snapshot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-initialize.html) in the background, slowing the drive.